# Calculate sum as per record type

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here is my sample excel file data

[image]

How can I calculate sum of all `CR` and `DR` type records separately?
Result should be

**Total Debit = XXX
Total Credit = XXX**

`Logic somthing like...`

```
Dim debit;
for each row in sheet1
    if(data of C column == dr)
        debit = debit + data of D column
    end if
end for
print debit;
```

I am not very much familiar with Excel 2010 so not sure how to code this so please give me some basic steps also to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this using formula    :

```
   =SUMIF(C:C,"=DR",D:D)
```

And if you want to get this using vba then you can write it like:

```
Dim debit, credit As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For x = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

        If UCase(.Cells(x, 3).Value) = "DR" Then
            debit = debit + .Cells(x, 4).Value
        Else
            If UCase(.Cells(x, 3).Value) = "CR" Then
                credit = credit + .Cells(x, 4).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

End With
```